# How to get data from multiple arrays with the same key?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this coding on my wordpress :

```
<?php
$meta_keys = get_post_custom_keys($post->ID);
foreach ($meta_keys as $meta_key) {
    $meta_values = get_post_custom_values($meta_key, $post->ID);
    print_r($meta_values);
    foreach ($meta_values as $meta_value) {
        $meta_value = maybe_unserialize($meta_value);
    }
}
?>
```

And the result is like this :

```
Array ( [0] => 30718 )
Array ( [0] => 69 )
Array ( [0] => 30717 )
Array ( [0] => a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:6:"_state";s:8:"expanded";}} )
Array ( [0] => 151 )
Array ( [0] => Read %%title%% %%page%% Manga %%sep%% %%sitename%% )
Array ( [0] => Read %%title%% manga online for free. )
Array ( [0] => )
Array ( [0] => 20 )
Array ( [0] => 30788 )
Array ( [0] => 1651670463:6 )
Array ( [0] => 6 )
```

From that result, I only want to take 1 data. Because I want to add the data automatically with the number 1.

The data I want to retrieve is : `Array ( [0] => 69 )` - *On the second line*

How can I retrieve one of the data from the result?

Comment: Use [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), to get the value of single meta key from a post.

Comment: @VijayHardaha I think the second method you suggested is much better than the first ;-)